# How to use local video instead of a Youtube URL?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, video, youtube

I am trying to have a full page video as my website landing page but currently it only allows me to use Youtube URL's and not local videos, this is okay most of the time but there are certain times when the video doesn't load for some reason.

Are there any changes I can make to this bootstrap code that will allow me to use a local video instead. I have tried putting in the filepath '/videos/video.mp4' and also url('videos/video.mp4')  with no avail. The code in the div is below;

```
<div id="P1" class="bg-player" style="display:block; 
margin: auto; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" 
data-property="{videoURL: 'http://www.youtube.com/videoURL',
containment:'.homevideo-container', quality: 'hd720', 
showControls: false, autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:38, 
stopAt:62, opacity:1}">
</div>
```

Help if you can please, I just want to use a video on the server rather than a Youtube video as it should be more reliable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide JFiddle of your trial?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Replace `src` with local mp4 directory e.g `xyz/videos/abc.mp4`

```
.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-16by9
{
   margin:0 auto
}
```

Comment: The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

CSS syntax: <div style="text-align:center">

Comment: @mlegg thanks for the help! :) have updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks this shows the video but it's not as responsive as the video was using the original bootstrap classes and such. Do you know if there's any way to just manipulate 'data-property' so that it takes local video files rather than using video tags?

Answer (score 0):

change the code to:
 containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}